# How do I count in Excel every time one range of strings contains a subset of another range of strings?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two ranges of strings in excel, and I want to use COUNTIF each time that one string is a subset of another string.

Example:

> Sheet1 has string:     ABCDEFG     and     Sheet2 has string:     BCD

BCD is a subset of ABCDEFG so it counts.

I currently have:
`=COUNTIF('Sheet1'!A1:A10,"*"&'Sheet2'!B1:B10&"*")`

...but it is not working and counting for those values.

Comment: What should the count be for a string like `ABCDEFGABCDEFG` in sheet1 and `BCD` in Sheet2?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post a data sample for the two ranges and the expected result. Explain the logic without referring to a particular Excel function. Countif cannot use a range as the second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Countif does not process a range as the second argument. If you have several strings that you want to count, you will need a Countif for each of the strings, then total the result.

[image]

Comment: You are correct, I needed to sadly enter all entries as an array instead of being able to input a range.